# Parsing Axios URL Param to String Array in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, rest, express, axios, express-validator

Sending a GET Request with axios:

```
await this.client.get('/endpoint', { params: { query: ['max', 'kevin'] } })
```

Results in a URL looking like this

```
Request GET /endpoint?query[]=max&query[]=kevin
```

How can I parse this to a string array?

Bonus points if someone knows how to check it in express-validator for format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the array to string with to `toString`:

```
await this.client.get("/endpoint", {
  params: { query: ["max", "kevin"].toString() },
});
```

This will change the URL to:

```
/endpoint?query=max,kevin
```

Then in the express-validator you can validate the array items with wildcard:

```
req.check('query.*').isLength({ max: 30 })
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought there is a library / middleware to parse this kind of array from axios.